# svnsync - couldn't get lock on destination repos

Tags: svn, svnsync

Using svnsync

```
$ svnsync --non-interactive sync ${REPO}
```

after an abort of the process there was this error message with retry

```
Failed to get lock on destination repos, currently held by 'svn.test.com:0e4e0d98-631d-0410-9a00-9330a90920b3'  
...  
Failed to get lock on destination repos, currently held by 'svn.test.com:0e4e0d98-631d-0410-9a00-9330a90920b3'   
svnsync: Couldn't get lock on destination repos after 10 attempts
```

Is there a way to fix this problem?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Actually, there is some functionality built into svnsync (since v1.7) that can "steal" the lock.

```
svnsync help sync
```

shows:

```
--steal-lock             : Steal locks as necessary.  Use, with caution,
                           if your mirror repository contains stale locks
                           and is not being concurrently accessed by another
                           svnsync instance.
```

and when I run it, I get a nice:

```
Stole lock previously held by '[hostname]'
```

So, you don't need the propdel thing after all

Comment: This option is not available in v1.6

Comment: This option is available only from v1.7

Answer (score 54):

You have to remove the lock property on the remote repository via svn command line on the remote site which has been left over from a failure during synchronization.

```
svn propdel --revprop -r0 svn:sync-lock file:///path/to/the/repository
```

Comment: No, not the remote repository--the locally synched (mirrored) repository.

Comment: Just a note, this might need to be the URL.  I run it from the destination machine, so the cmd would be:  svn propdel --revprop -r0 svn:sync-lock http://localhost/svn/repo

Comment: Worth noting IMO that sync-locks are always applied to revision 0.

Answer (score 11):

Technically, it is the destination repository that you need to delete the property from, not necessarily the remote repository, as the destination could be local. So for this specific question:

```
svn propdel --revprop -r0 svn:sync-lock ${REPO}
```

Answer (score 3):

Removing the Lock worked for me.  However, I had to use a slightly different command, as I needed to send the username and password of the account to use to unlock the account.

```
svn pdel --revprop -r 0 --username ??? --password ??? svn:sync-lock file:///path/to/the/repository
```

I also had to run this command from the drive that the repository was on. (change to d: in the command prompt before running the command, if my Repository was on d:)

Prior to entering the username and password, when I ran the command I got the following error:

```
revprop change blocked by pre-revprop-change hook (exit code 255)
```

I found and opened the `pre-revprop-change` hook file, and it had code in there listing only a certain username that could make the required changes.  Using that username and password in the above command removed the hook.

Answer (score 3):

To confirm the presence of lock(although the err obviously tells it), run proplist with `-verbose`

```
svn pl --revprop -v -r 0 file:///svn/slave
```

then delete the prop as necessary!

Comment: this helped a lot, for me the property was svn:rdump-lock (running svnrdump).

Answer (score 2):

You have to do two things to solve the problem.  One is deleted the lock as noted above.  Then you have to edit the pre-revprop-change.tmpl file to be empty, and make it executable.  Use chmod +x on Linux/Unix/Mac but change the file name to pre-revprop-change.bat on Windows.  After this you can load dump files into your repository and then mirror it where ever you need.

Comment: revprops are required for syncing in the first place, so one assumes that has already been configured if we encounter an error _during_ the sync process.